# Changing the position of Image view at run time

Tags: android

I want to make an application in which a Loading text is there and some dot images in front of them. I want that images are shown after some time period continuously until background work is completed or can i change the position of an image view at run time which is in absolute layout. Please share exact running code, I need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to move imageview then you have to take relative layout and you need to increase leftPadding to move imageview horizontally.

```
ImageView leaf = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

par = (LayoutParams)leaf.getLayoutParams();
par.leftMargin += 30;

leaf.setLayoutParams(par);
```

Comment: leftMargin is not available. Only width and height are available

Answer (score 1):

You could call setVisiblity(View.GONE) to hide the loading animation whenever you've loaded the page

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `AbsoluteLayout` since it's deprecated.

You can set the Text invisible as Kurru said or use an Animation to make it go out of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move imageview in absolute layout use setX() and setY() method .But this method are not supported in below 3.0 verson